# Things are happening outside my for loop before its done (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm sure I've seen this before and know the answer to it but after 12 hours... my mind is complete mush.

I have a for loop in which I am trying to concatenate onto a string so that AFTER I can complete the string (thus completing a nice little table) that I had hoped to then insert into my html and show the user.

However, the things at the end of my function (after my for loop) are getting called before the for loop ever does....

```
function getEntries() {

$('#entryTotalsDiv').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> ... retrieving form totals.');

var entryTotalsTable = "<table id='entryTable' class='display' style='border:1px;'><thead><tr><th>Form Name</th><th>Hash</th><th>Entries</th></tr></thead>" +
        "<tbody>"

//Get rows ONE at a time.
var countNumber = 1;
for (var frm = 0; frm < numberOfForms; frm++) {
    $.post('ajax/getEntries.aspx',
    {
        'formNumber': frm
    },
    function (data) {
        entryTotalsTable += "<tr><td>" + data[0].formName + "</td><td>" + data[0].formHash + "</td><td>" + data[0].formEntryCount + "</td></tr>";

        //Now go and update the Form Retrieval div -- add 1 to the frm Number
        $('#formNamesDiv').html(countNumber + ' of ' + numberOfForms + ' retrieved.');
        countNumber++;            
    });
}
entryTotalsTable += "</tbody></table>";
$('#entriesDiv').html(entryTotalsTable);
//Now bind the table to the DataTables JQ script
$('#entryTable').dataTable();
$('#entryTable').show('slow');
```

}

If you notice, I wanted to close up the Table html at the end, but this gets called before my for loop is finished, thus screwing up my string...

?

```
entryTotalsTable += "</tbody></table>";
$('#entriesDiv').html(entryTotalsTable);
//Now bind the table to the DataTables JQ script
$('#entryTable').dataTable();
$('#entryTable').show('slow');
```

}

Comment: You are making an Ajax request inside the loop. Ajax is asynchronous, so the code after the loop is executed before the Ajax callback gets executed.

Comment: where is numberOfForms defined? or is my mind mush too??

Comment: @Felix:  That ought to be an answer.  :)

Comment: Another note: I think you cannot even rely on the fact that the callbacks are called in the order of the loop. A response from an earlier query might be received earlier than the one from a later one.

Comment: @cHao: Imo an answer would solve the problem.... this is just explaining *why* it does not work.... and I'm tired ;)

Comment: I noticed that.... I would get 65 AFTER 70 of the form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post is asynchronous, meaning that it's firing off all the requests in the loop as fast as it can, and then exiting the loop.  It doesn't wait for a response.  When the response comes back, your row function is then called... but by then, all the posts have been sent on their way.

See the answers to this question here...
[How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req)

You'll need to change from $.post to $.ajax

Comment: Making several *synchronous* Ajax calls might result in freezing the browser (or at least the page)! Everything that takes longer than 100ms will be noticed by the user.

Comment: Very true - hopefully numberOfForms isn't more than 2!

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to save every response in an array and test in every callback whether the current count is equal to the total count. Something like:

```
var countNumber = 1,
    allData = [];

function runWhenFinished() {
    if(countNumber === numberOfForms) {
        var entryTotalsTable = "<table id='entryTable' class='display' style='border:1px;'><thead><tr><th>Form Name</th><th>Hash</th><th>Entries</th></tr></thead>" + "<tbody>";

        for(var i = 0, l = allData.length; i < l; i++) {
             entryTotalsTable += "<tr><td>" + allData[i].formName + "</td><td>" + allData[i].formHash + "</td><td>" + allData[i].formEntryCount + "</td></tr>";
        }

        entryTotalsTable += "</tbody></table>";
        $('#entriesDiv').html(entryTotalsTable);
        //Now bind the table to the DataTables JQ script
        $('#entryTable').dataTable();
        $('#entryTable').show('slow');
    }
}

for(var frm = 0; frm < numberOfForms; frm++) {
    (function(frm) {
        $.post('ajax/getEntries.aspx',{'formNumber': frm}, function (data) {
            allData[frm] = data[0];
            countNumber++;
            $('#formNamesDiv').html(countNumber + ' of ' + numberOfForms + ' retrieved.');
            runWhenFinished();
        });
    }(frm));
}
```

I'm sure this can still be improved, but you get the idea.

---

If you really make 70 requests then you might want to rethink your strategy anyway. 70 simultaneous requests is a lot.

E.g. you could make *one* request and prove the minimum and maximum number of that should be retrieved / updated / whatever the method is doing.

Comment: +1 - Doesn't really answer the question, but does provide a better option.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion -- I am doing the count thing and then just calling the next function when the count reaches my limit.

THE REASON I am doing one call at a time instead of one large call (like I was doing) is that I was trying to give the user some feedback (so with each return, I am updating the count of returns to the users -- the ONE call just took quite a while) 

**I also thought it would be SUPER COOL to fill in my table dynamically on the fly, this was working but all the good jquery gridview stuff was not getting applied (i.e. paging, etc) so I went away from that.